# Copying a .dll file to a new .dll file using Powershell Add-Type

Tags: powershell, dll, compilation, copy

I recently learned the ability to compile `.dll` files from C# code in Powershell using the Add-Type command and I got to wondering.

Is it possible to perhaps load an already existing `.dll` and copy/place it in another folder under a different name using the `Add-Type` Command?

Example C# compiling:

```
$code = @'
    using System:
    using System.Management.Automation;   // Windows PowerShell namespace.

    namespace DLL
    {
      class DLL
      {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Hello World");

        }
      }
    }
'@
$InitialPath = "C:\Some\Path\To\My.dll"
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -OutputAssembly $InitialPath
```

Now I was wondering if it is possible to use Add-Type to create some sort of "COPY" of `My.dll` and place it in another folder.

I was trying something like:

```
$FinalPath = "C:\Another\Path\To\MyOther.dll"
Add-Type -Path $InitialPath -OutputAssembly $FinalPath
```

This doesn't work but perhaps it clarifies what my intentions are?
Please help, thanks. ;)

Comment: `Copy-Item -Path $InitialPath -Destination $FinalPath`?

Comment: I know this is the easy solution but I was wondering if it is possible to accomplish this with `Add-Type` hence the question

Comment: It's odd that it does not error out either.

Comment: exactly my point. So what does happen? ^^